# Input Validation is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to JavaScript and I have a question regarding input validation in JavaScript. I have a form a user enters 3 values, and if any of the values don't meet my validation criteria, I want to reject the user input. Currently, all inputs, even if failing validation are being added to the list:

```
 const validateSearch = () => {
   
    if((firstName.length === 0) || (lastName.length === 0) || (age.length === 0) || (!isNumber(age)   || age > 10)) {
        setErrorMessage(!errorMessageOn);
        return
      }   
      setErrorMessage(errorMessageOn);    
     

  }
```

```
  const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState("")
  const [lastName, setlastName] = useState("")
  const [age, setage] = useState("")
```

```
const addEmployeeToList = () => {
    let newEmployee = [{firstName, lastName, age}]
    validateSearch()
    

      return setEmployees(employee => [...employee, ...newEmployee])
    
    setfirstName("")
    setlastName("")
    setage("")  
  }
```

Again, I only want to add the item to the list when all values are entered correctly, otherwise discard user input.

Comment: Never validate inputs in the front end, it can be changed by the user.

Comment: What are `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`? Are they DOM elements? Perhaps you meant `firstName.value.length`, `lastName.value.length`, and `age.value.length`?

Comment: Where/how are you adding the item to the list? Where are you calling `validateSearch`?

Comment: I updated code for more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `validateSearch` return `true` if the validation passes and return `false` if it does not pass.

Then in `addEmployeeToList` you can return early if `validateSearch` returns `false`.

When you return early, `setEmployees`, `setfirstName`, `setlastName`, and `setage` never execute.

```
   const validateSearch = () => {
    if (
      firstName.length === 0 ||
      lastName.length === 0 ||
      age.length === 0 ||
      !isNumeric(age) ||
      +age > 10
    ) {
      setErrorMessage(true);
      return false;
    } else {
      setErrorMessage(false);
      return true;
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addEmployeeToList();
  };

  const addEmployeeToList = () => {
    let newEmployee = [{ firstName, lastName, age }];
    const isValid = validateSearch();

    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }

    setEmployees((employee) => [...employee, ...newEmployee]);

    setfirstName("");
    setlastName("");
    setage("");
  };
```

[image: Edit eager-swartz-1g6w02]

---

As your form begins to get more complicated, you may want to introduce a library to handle validation such as `yup`.

One added benefit of this approach is that users will see a more detailed message as to why validation failed.

```
const userSchema = object({
  firstName: string().required().trim(),
  lastName: string().required().trim(),
  age: number().required().positive().integer().lessThan(10)
});
```

```
  const validateSearch = async () => {
    setErrorMessages([]);
    try {
      const isValid = await userSchema.validate({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        age
      });
      return !!isValid;
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessages(err.errors);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addEmployeeToList();
  };
```

[image: Edit react input validation with yup]